# How to close the auto completion/suggestion box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have input search box.
When enter some words its populate some suggestions automatically.
when I click enter still it shows auto suggestion box.
I want to close them on mouse over/enter.

Below is my code..

```
if($("#keywords").val().length < 3){
    $("#keywords").autocomplete("off"):
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
if($("#keywords").val().length < 3){
    $("#keywords").attr("autocomplete","off"):
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling [close](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-close) should do it:

```
$("#keywords").autocomplete('close');
```